# Junit mocking error : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I am using `spring data JPA` for creating services and for unit testing I am using `Junit` and `mockito`. In following code I am trying to do junit testing for service class.

Room account mapping service class is dependent on Room Investigator mapping service class so I used mockito for mocking room Investigator mapping service class method but that method calling one more method of same class.

I tried like below but I am getting error in mockito. Can any one please tell me how I can do mocking?

**TestRoomAccountMappingService class**

```
public class TestRoomAccountMappingService {
    @MockBean
    RoomAccountMappingRepository roomAccountMapRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoomAccountMappingService roomAccountMappingService;

    @Autowired
    RoomInvestigatorMappingService roomInvestMapService;

    @Test
    public void deleteAccountMapping() {

        Integer[] RoomAllocationId= {1839};         

        //here getting error
        Mockito.when(roomInvestMapService.returnRoomWithinClusterByRoomAllocationID(1839)).thenReturn(RoomAllocationId);

        RoomAccountMapping roomAcctMap= new RoomAccountMapping();
        roomAcctMap.setnRoomAllocationId(1);

        List<RoomAccountMapping> roomList= new ArrayList<>();
        roomList.add(roomAcctMap);      

        Mockito.when(roomAccountMapRepository.findByNRoomAllocationId(1839)).thenReturn(roomList);

        Boolean actual = roomAccountMappingService.deleteAccountMapping(1839);

        assertEquals(true, actual );
    }
}
```

**Failure Trace**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at com.spacestudy.service.TestRoomAccountMappingService.deleteAccountMapping(TestRoomAccountMappingService.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you...

> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

This might be the case here:

```
Mockito.when(roomInvestMapService.returnRoomWithinClusterByRoomAllocationID(1839))...
```

...because:

```
@Autowired
RoomInvestigatorMappingService roomInvestMapService;
```

...is probably not a mock, since you don't use `@MockBean`. At least, to me, that seems currently to be the most plausible explanation.